# Can I double click a hyphenated selector in Atom

Tags: regex, atom-editor, double-click, hyphenation

I would like the ability to double click a hyphenated CSS class name in Atom and have it select the entire class. eg `.my-class-name`.

I heard mention of the the 'Non word characters' in settings but this appears as a regex formula I'm not familiar with `/\()"':,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`?-…`

What do I edit to make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your right

go to `atom preferences` scroll down to `Non Word Characters` & paste this;

To select both hyphens and underscores;

```
"./\\()\"':,.;<>~!@#%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"
```

Just hyphens;

```
"./\\()\"':,.;<>~!@#%^&*|+=[]{}`~?_"
```

Just underscores;

```
"./\\()\"':,.;<>~!@#%^&*|+=[]{}`~?-"
```